# Making a PHP Slot timetable for radio

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently developing an Online Radio stations website I have developed everything but there is one thing I cant seem to get my head around. I am trying to do the Dj booking slots.

The idea:
Dj's get to pick and choose their slots from a HTML dropdown menu from 00:00 to 23:45 in 15 minute increments so they can do different length timeslots I,e (10:00 to 10:45) <-- I can insert that into a db ***easy***
*However*
If **DJ - 1** books 10:00 to 10:45 I would like it to remove 10:00 10:15 and 10:30 from the dropdown menu (again easy *only if your checking 1 slot*)

How do I get it to remove the booked slots if their is more than one booking?

```
**Dj - 1** has booked 10:00 to 10:45.

**DJ - 2** has booked 13:00 to 14:00.

**DJ - 3** has booked 17:00 to 19:00.
```

How do i get it to ***JUST*** display

```
00:00 - 09:45 in 15 minute increments.

10:45 - 12:45 in 15 minute increments.

14:00 - 16:45 in 15 minute increments.

19:00 - 29:45 in 15 minute increments.
```

I can't use ***predefined slots*** as when the public view the timetable it will show a 45 minute show as three 15 minute slots instead of one 45 minute show

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I highly suggest posting any code you have tried to accomplish what you are trying to do. Stack Overflow is a website where others will help but they want to see some effort on your part and any code you have tried.

Comment: @dalelandry I have not done any code as I don't know where to start to be quite honest. I have tried other places before coming here but theres not much support other than a couple of discords and here.

Comment: Okay, so you are saving the time slots in a database, how are you saving the values in the db exactly are you using datetime format or a string like `10:45`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are definitely working with 15 minute slots, my approach would be to save an array of the slots instead of a start/end time.

So instead of `10:00 to 10:45`, i would save `["10:00", "10:15", "10:30"]` to the database instead.

After that you can just fetch all the booked slot-arrays from db and `array_diff` it with the complete time-slot array.

```
$all_time_slots = ["00:00", "00:15", ..., "23:30", "23:45"];
$booked_time_slots = ["10:00", "10:15", "10:30"];
$available_slots = array_diff($all_time_slots, $booked_time_slots);
```

Comment: This sounds good but how do I overcome the issue that is when a DJ selects 10:00 - 10:45 how will the array know to remove 10:15 and 10:30?

Comment: You can create start/end `DateTime` objects and keep subtracting 15 mins from the end until start == end. Please mark my answer if it helped you :)